# the height of a tree given n nodes and a condition

Tags: combinatorics, trees, discrete-mathematics

I came across a question on which I got totally stuck :( a sort of homework question)

A weight-balanced tree is a binary tree in which for each node. The number of nodes in the left sub tree is at least half and at most twice the number of nodes in the right sub tree. The maximum possible height (number of nodes on the path from the root to the farthest leaf) of such a tree on n nodes is best described by which of the following?

```
a) log_2 n  
b) log_{4/3} n  
c) log_3 {n} 
d) log_{3/2} n
```

I cant imagine to solve this one. Intuitive based answer is most welcome.

Comment: Did you try drawing some trees with fixed numbers of nodes, to see how high a tree you could make?

Comment: no I did not, I will try and get back to you

Comment: thanks for the suggestion! it actually helped. it should be option d .because one of the two subtrees can have 2/3rd of the total nodes remainig .

Comment: I'm confused: for $h=2$ there is only one such tree, right? $2\cdot 0 < 1$.

Comment: @neerajDorle I'm glad it worked. Playing with examples is a good way to start, if you can't see how to prove something or can't tell what it is you're trying to prove.

Comment: This is a dump of an exercise problem, not a question. If you have a specific question regarding the wording of the problem or concrete steps in your own attempts at solving the problem, feel free to edit accordingly and we can reopen the question. See also [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/a/470/) for our homework policy, and [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/594) for a relevant discussion. You may also want to check out our [reference questions](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/q/599/). If you are uncertain how to improve your question, why not ask around in [chat]?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The height of a tree is 1 + the height of its highest subtree. Which way of distributing the nodes to the subtrees will allow you to maximize that parameter?

> Put $\frac 13 n$ nodes into the left tree and $\frac 23 n$ into the right one (or vice versa).

If you apply this recursively, what do you get for the height?

> You get the recurrence $h(1) = 1$, $h(n) = 1 + h(\frac 23 n)$, $n>1$. This solves to
>  $h(n) = 1+\log_{\frac 32}n$.